# Phalcon - Module exception if does not exist

Tags: php, phalcon

I have set the Route:

```
$router->add('/:module/:controller/:action/:params', [
      'module' => 1,
      'controller' => 2,
      'action' => 3,
      'params' => 4
]);
```

When I enter URL to the browser, for example: auth/login/index and module under this URL does not exist, so it throws an exception:

```
Phalcon\Mvc\Application\Exception: Module 'auth' isn't registered in the application container
```

How can I catch this exception?

**SOLUTION**:

```
    $router->add('/:module/:controller/:action/:params', [
        'module' => 1,
        'controller' => 2,
        'action' => 3,
        'params' => 4
    ])->beforeMatch(function($uri) use ($application) {

        $modules = $application->getModules();

        $moduleName = array_filter(explode('/', $uri))[1];

        if(!isset($modules[$moduleName]))
            return false;

        return true;
    });
```

In beforeMatch method I check If module exist.

Comment: Do you get an uncaught exception? I catch it in my index.php file.

Answer (score 3):

For second param you can use closure and check via

```
if ($di->has('modulename'))
```

**Update1**

As I can see https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/application.zep#L232

you can use event manager and return `false` from `beforeStartModule` if module not found in DI

```
if typeof eventsManager == "object" {
    if eventsManager->fire("application:beforeStartModule", this, moduleName) === false {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Update2**

Also you can use dispatcher setting:

```
// Initialize the Dispatcher
$di->setShared('dispatcher', function() use ($eventsManager) {
    $dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;

    // Attach a listener for type "dispatch:beforeException"
    $eventsManager->attach('dispatch:beforeException', function($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {
       /**
        * @var \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception $exception
        * @var \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher $dispatcher
        */
       switch ($exception->getCode()) {
           case \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND:
           case \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_ACTION_NOT_FOUND:
           case ANY OTHER CODE HERE:
               $dispatcher->forward([
                   'controller' => 'error',
                   'action'     => 'show404'
               ]);
               return false;
       }
    });

    // Setting up the Dispatcher component
    $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace('your_default_namespace_here');

    // Obtain the Events Manager from the DI and bind the eventsManager to the module dispatcher
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

    return $dispatcher;
});
```

Comment: I do not understand. Where can i use second param?

Comment: I've tried it, but if I return false, I get an error: Call to a member function getContent()

Comment: Sorry but event manager dispatch:beforeException here does not work. I've tried it.

Comment: I have solution above - beforeMatch method